# Did Apple deprecate, eliminate, or standardize the "Universal" push notification certificates?

Tags: ios, xcode, apn

We've been using Apple's APN service for a long time.  A few years back Apple introduced a "Universal" certificate that could be used for both development and production. We switched to this approach because it's one less certificate to renew, and it seemed to work fine.

Now, all relevant links I can find about the Universal APN certs are dead, and the APN portal only allows generating two separate certs again.  Did Universal APN certs go away, or is the Production APN now "universal" by default?

The text in the "Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide"says:

> **APNs Provider Certificates**
> Your APNs provider certificate, which you
> obtain as explained in “Configure push notifications” in Xcode Help,
> enables connection to both the APNs Production and Development
> environments.

Notice the section head references plural certificates, but the text says you can use one for both.  It's confusing!

[Dead link, still being served by Apple when searching for this info](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev11b059073?sub=dev1eb5dfe65)

Comment: When I go into certificates in my developer account the second option under "services" in certificates is "Apple push notification service ssl (sandbox and production)"

Comment: Right.  This seems to be the same as the "universal" cert, but without being called that?

Comment: I guess they changed it to make it clearer.  What does "Universal" mean?  "(Sandbox and production)" is explicit in what it is for.